# Access remote computer's network from client if RDP is available

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, forwarding

I have access to the remote machine via RDP (static ip and port forwarding). This machine can access another machine on in local network.

Is it possible to somehow "passthrough" this remote local network so that my own machine would be able to connect to it?

Answer (score 0):

You can forward RDP traffic at the network level as many times as you like, but once RDP connects to a workstation, the connection has found its point of termination. I suppose an application could be written to listen for RDP traffic and then forward it to another device, but given the fact you can do this with regular port-forwarding it seems unlikely to exist.

The option at your disposal is to connect to the first computer, then from it, connect to the second. You could also configure the second computer to accept its *own* RDP traffic (listening on a different port if necessary).